# How to disable back pressure or how to trop flow files in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

After merging my flow file records, the "original" flow-files were not needed. How can I drop the original flow files? Or can I disable back pressure on a specific queue? Already set "FlowFile Expiration" to 1 seconds but want another way to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Delete any queues consisting the `original` relationship. Now, if you will enter the processor's configuration, you will see under `Settings`(while the processor is stopped) in the right top corner a list of relationships to auto terminate.  Mark the `original` queue and save. Now anything destined for the `original` queue will be deleted.